# Incorporate the function into for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe called "commit.277", with 600 list of investor_ids and deal_ids. I want to construct dyad_id based on investor_ids and deal_ids. Here is the function below (provided by someone from Stackoverflow):

```
function(investor_id,deal_id){
    paste0("1",
           # this rule adds 0 if the ids are shorter/longer
           # but should be changed to match what you need
           paste0(rep("0",(7 - nchar(investor_id)-nchar(deal_id))),collapse = ""),
           investor_id,
           "0",
           deal_id
    )
}
```

However, with this function, I can only get the result one by one, I have 600 ids to create in a dataframe. So is there a way (something like a for loop?) I can use this function to generate the result in the dataframe very quickly?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

To use your function as it is you can use `mapply`. If your function is called `fn_name` you could do :

```
result <- mapply(fn_name, commit.277$investor_ids, commit.277$deal_ids)
```

However, I think your function can be vectorised which will avoid using `mapply` if you share information about your data and expected output.

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for your help! However, when I tried using your code, the error says "Error in rep("0", (7 - nchar(investor_id) - nchar(deal_id))) : 
  invalid 'times' argument". Is this because my function does not refer to investor_id and deal_id clearly?

Comment: @QZZhang As I said earlier please add an example dataset along with expected output. It is difficult to debug without any data.